# Powershell XML reading the nodes with tags

Tags: xml, powershell

I would like to add a new node `<executables>` into the existing `<project/files>` node in the XML. For that I have written the following code:

```
# Load the XML file into the XmlDocument object
$xml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.Load("C:\path\to\file.xml")

# Select the parent node where you want to add the new node
$parent = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//project/files")

# Create a new node under the parent node
$newNode = $xml.CreateElement("executables")

# Add content to the new node
$content = $xml.CreateTextNode("C:\executable.exe")
$newNode.AppendChild($content)

# Add the new node to the parent node
$parent.AppendChild($newNode)

# Save the changes to the XML file
$xml.Save("C:\path\to\file.xml")
```

However, the code does not seem to work, because the variable `$parent` has value of `$null` after calling the function `$xml.SelectSingleNode("//parent/node")`:

```
# Select the parent node where you want to add the new node
$parent = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//parent/node")
```

If I however, remove all XML Namespaces from the `<project>` node in the XML file, then the above code works. I would like to ignore tags and simply load the `<project>` without having to specify the XML Namespaces, because the content of the XML Namespaces might change from XML file to XML file. Is that possible?

Not working XML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.google.com/" xmlns="http://www.google.com/apx" version="22.04" build="11114914" target="targetArchitecture">
      <files>
        <executables>C:\executable.exe</executables>
      </files>
    </project>
```

Working XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project>
  <files>
    <executables>C:\executable.exe</executables>
  </files>
</project>
```

Comment: This is the classic problem of default namespace (`xmlns="http://www.google.com/apx`) that needs to be acknowledged in any XPath parsing. System.Xml library can handle namespaces including for [`SelectSingleNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode?view=net-7.0) .

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to face the namespace issue head-on in order to get there:

```
#declare your default namespace
$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("xx", "http://www.google.com/apx")

#now search for $parent properly using the default namespace
$parent = $xml.SelectNodes('//xx:files',$ns)

#create the new node; note that the 2nd argument is necessary in order
#to suppress the inclusion of an empty xmlns "attribute" in the new node
$newNode = $xml.CreateElement("executables", "http://www.google.com/apx")

# From here, it's the same: Add content to the new node
$content = $xml.CreateTextNode("C:\executable.exe")
$newNode.AppendChild($content)
# Add the new node to the parent node
$parent.AppendChild($newNode)
```

Comment: What does "xx" mean in the following lines?
"""$ns.AddNamespace("xx", "http://www.google.com/apx")
$parent = $xml.SelectNodes('//xx:files',$ns)"""

Comment: @SimpleThings It doesn't mean anything - it's just a random string used as a placeholder for the default namespace (you have to have something for this to work). You can use anything else, like the name of your cat or whatever :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a namespace issue.  Using Xml Linq

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$outputFilename = 'c:\temp\test1.xml'

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$project = $doc.Root
$ns = $project.GetDefaultNamespace()

$files = $project.Element($ns + 'files')

$executables = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($ns + [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('executables'), 'C:\executable.exe')
$files.Add($executables)

$doc.Save($outputFilename)
```